# when I try to push my project in build i got a below error in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

when I try to push my project in build i got a below error in next.js
static/media/thread.4e53ce56.js from Terser

```
  x 'import', and 'export' cannot be used outside of module code
   ,-[1:1]
 1 | import {Buffer} from 'node:buffer';
   : ^^^^^^
 2 | import crypto from 'node:crypto';
 3 | import {parentPort} from 'node:worker_threads';
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse input file
    1: Syntax Error
Error: 
  x 'import', and 'export' cannot be used outside of module code
   ,-[1:1]
 1 | import {Buffer} from 'node:buffer';
   : ^^^^^^
 2 | import crypto from 'node:crypto';
 3 | import {parentPort} from 'node:worker_threads';
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse input file
    1: Syntax Error


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

Comment: Did you manage to work around it? I had the same thing trying to use persisted queries link from apollo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77917258/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-filename-argument-must-be-of-type-string

Answer (score 0):

I do found same issue when use this library in my component

```
import { sha256 } from "crypto-hash";
```

Replacing with this solve the issue

```
import { createHash } from "crypto";

function calculateSHA256(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer): Promise<string> {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
  const hash = createHash("sha256");
  hash.update(buffer);
  return Promise.resolve(hash.digest("hex"));
}
```

usage:

```
const fileHash = await calculateSHA256(arrayBuffer);
```