# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "filename" argument must be of type string or an instance of URL. Received an instance of URL

Tags: apollo-client, automatic-persisted-queries

I'm getting this very weird error trying to use Apollo persisted queries link, as instructed [here](https://github.com/DmitryTsepelev/graphql-ruby-persisted_queries), and I'm very confused of what it means, since if 'instance of URL' is a valid type and that function is receiving it like that, it shouldn't be a type error.

My link looks like this:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: apiUri,
  fetchOptions: {
    agent: new Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
    next: {
      revalidate: 300,
    },
  },
})

const timeoutLink = new ApolloLinkTimeout(15_000)

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      log.error(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${JSON.stringify(
          locations
        )}, Path: ${path}, operation: ${operation.operationName}`
      )
    )
  if (networkError) {
    if (networkError.message.includes("Timeout exceeded")) {
      log.error(`Timeout exceeded Operation Name: ${operation.operationName}`)
    } else {
      log.error(
        `[Network error]: ${networkError}, operation: ${operation.operationName}`
      )
    }
  }
})

const persistedQueriesLink = createPersistedQueryLink({ sha256 })

const links = process.env.VERCEL_ENV
  ? [errorLink, timeoutLink, persistedQueriesLink, httpLink]
  : [errorLink, persistedQueriesLink, httpLink]

export const apolloLink = ApolloLink.from(links)
```

Comment: Can you add how you get `apiUri`? Generally, there can be more than one class called `URL`, so this could stem from multiple polyfills fighting for the upper hand.

Comment: Its just a string:
`const apiUri = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_API_URL`

Comment: Rest assure there is nothing wrong with it, just removing the persistedQueriesLink from the concatenation makes everything work again

Comment: Actually, to be more specific, the error stops when I remove the crypto-hash import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to origin from a call in `crypto-hash`:

```
const threadFilePath = new URL('thread.js', import.meta.url);
new Worker(threadFilePath);
```

This probably causes problems with `esbuild` in the `Next.js` toolchain.

For what it's worth, you don't need an external package to create a hash, so I'd recommend you replace that external `sha256` function with node's `crpyto` functionality:

```js
import crypto from "node:crypto";
function sha256(data) {
  const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
  hash.update(data);
  return hash.digest("hex");
}
```